# Change label in ggpairs upper panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggally

Do you know how to change the labels in an upper panel in `ggpairs` (`Ggally` package)? I found how to change size, font but not label. Here I want to shorten the label ("set" pour setosa etc...). I tried to put that in `labels=c("set", "ver", "vir")` or `upper=list(params=list(size=8),labels=c("set", "ver", "vir"))` but it doesn't work.

```
ggpairs(iris, columns=c(2:4), title="variable analysis", colour="Species",
        lower=list(params=list(size=2)), upper=list(params=list(size=8)))
```

[image: iris DATA GGPAIRS]

Comment: I can't test it, because your code is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but you could try `theme(text= element_text(size = 8))` for smaller labels.

Comment: Thanks, I just put a reproductible example with iris dataset. But that I want is to change the labels (versicolor in "ver" etc...), not their size.

Comment: Also, the change of computer give not the same result in the image saved ! here it  could be correct, but on my laptop, labels are hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually the same as @Mike's solution, but in one line.

```
levels(iris$Species) <- c("set", "ver", "vir")
ggplairs(<...>)
```

Here's another, more flexible proposal if you have many levels and do not want to abbreviate them by hand: trim levels to a desired length.

```
levels(iris$Species) <- strtrim(levels(iris$Species), 3)
ggplairs(<...>)
```

And by the way, the `width` parameter is also vectorized:

```
rm(iris)
strtrim(levels(iris$Species), c(1, 3, 5))
#[1] "s"     "ver"   "virgi"
```

Comment: Jeez, I thought the whole point was doing it without changing the data that generated the plot.

Comment: @MikeWise Same thing applies to `levels(gplt$data$Species)`. The point is, there is no need to iterate over levels (imagine there's 100 factor levels).

Comment: I like how you renamed the levels. I should have tried something like that, what I did looked completely inelegant but it was late and I was sleepy.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit ugly, but you could do this (rename the levels in the plot):

```
library(GGally)
gplt <- ggpairs(iris, columns=c(2:4), 
        title="variable analysis", 
        colour="Species", 
        lower=list(params=list(size=2)), 
        upper=list(params=list(size=6)))

levels(gplt$data$Species)[levels(gplt$data$Species)=="versicolor"] <- "ver"
levels(gplt$data$Species)[levels(gplt$data$Species)=="virginica"] <- "vir"
levels(gplt$data$Species)[levels(gplt$data$Species)=="setosa"] <- "set"

print(gplt)
```

[image]